# How to show results of individual test pass/fail in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins

We're using Scala + Maven + ScalaTest runner + Jenkins. We have JUnit-style XML output going here:

```
test_dir/target/scalatest-reports/
```

Right now we can see entire build pass/fail, or dig through the verbose Console Output to see test pass/fail (not ideal), but I'm sure there's a better way.

I've tried several of the post-build steps such as:

- Aggregate downstream test results
- Publish xUnit test result report

But can't get a table of test results working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should better describe your symptoms. JUnit-style XML report is the basic form of test report supported by Jenkins/Hudson, so I suppose the problem is relatively simple. Please compare your configuration with the following example:

---

[image]

---

I would suggest the following:

1. Check you configuration (it is likely jenkins is not able to find the actual report file)
2. Look through the console output to make sure there is no warning message related to XML report file
3. Verify XML report is not empty and valid
4. Try to use [JUnitReport tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) to generate HTML form
5. Finally, switch to [TestNG](http://testng.org) if you can

Answer (score 6):

There are two options:

- ScalaTest can generate HTML reports. Just add

  (testOptions in Test) += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/scalatest-report")

to your 'build.sbt'. Running 'sbt test' will then generate an HTML report in the folder 'target/scalatest-report'.

In Jenkins you can use the 'Publish HTML' plugin to capture this report for a build. The test html becomes then available for each build and also on job page.

- ScalaTest also generates normal JUnit XML reports in the 'target/test-reports' folder. The Jenkins these reports can be captured with the 'Publish JUnit XML test report' post-build-action which is default available in Jenkins I think.

Both solutions give a view on the test results and they can be used together.

Comment: a nice suggestion, especially when you have a multi module sbt project. Using Publish HTML, one can have links for the test reports of all the modules.

Comment: Publish HTML is not a default Jenkins plugin. It requires the HTML Publisher plugin.

Comment: I have a multimodule sbt project. How to consolidate all the result using sbt command ?

Comment: Unfortunately the ScalaTest html report cannot be accumulated. But accumulating the ScalaTest junit reports is possible. By using `aggregate(module1, module1)` in a multi-module sbt project, I think the ScalaTest junit reports get aggregated already.